# Why is this get parameter not equal to a string?

Tags: php

given a url:

scrape.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coldwellbanker.com%2Fagent%3 ...etc

```
$url = $_GET['u'];
$url2 = 'http://www.coldwellbanker.com/agent?action=detail&agentId=121759&mode=detail';
var_dump($url==$url2);

//This prints out bool(false)
```

Why is the $_GET parameter not identical to the string equivalent in single quotes?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()` directly on `$url`?

Comment: yes. this is weird. var_dump of $url gives me string(84)  and var_dump of $url2 gives me string(76)

Comment: Since you get 8 characters too much (or 2 times 4), is it possible your 'scrape.php?u=...' call is using `&amp;` instead of `&`?

Comment: what do you mean php call? I'm only decoding a url that was urlencoded() with php... i.e. not using any html entities anywhere, but i like the thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

Given a URL:

```
http://localhost/gettest.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Ftest%3Dtest
```

And this Script:

```
$url = $_GET['u'];
var_dump($url);
$url2 = "http://google.com?test=test&test1=test1";
var_dump($url2);
var_dump($url == $url2);
```

Output is:

```
string 'http://google.com?test=test' (length=27)
string 'http://google.com?test=test&test1=test1' (length=39) 
boolean false
```

Which leads me to believe that the ampersand is being evaluated by the $_GET to be a separate arg. Perhaps you should base64encode your URL to ensure it will work.

Comment: As expected, using base64_encode() to encode your string will ensure it is transmitted properly via $_GET.

Comment: Do you mean the URL will be base64 encoded. Like scrape.php?u=BASE64ENCODEDSTRING. And then can I base 64 decode the result?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the URL you're passing it, is thinking the & is actually parameters to your original script:

so if you do:

```
<?php echo $_GET['u'];?>
```

You will return: http://www.coldwellbanker.com/agent?action=detail49

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>

Array ( [u] => http://www.coldwellbanker.com/agent?action=detail [agentId] => 121759 [mode] => detail )
```

One way to get around it could be by doing something like:

```
<?php
$url = end(explode('u=', $_SERVER['argv'][0]));
$url2 = 'http://www.coldwellbanker.com/agent?action=detail&agentId=121759&mode=detail';
echo var_dump( $url==$url2 );
?>
```

returns:

```
bool(true)
```

Comment: $_GET variable are already passed through url_decode according to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Found the issue. Changed my answer

Comment: I thought this might have been the issue, but if I print_r($_GET); it just gives me [u]=http://example.com?s=1&j=3 etc.. basically what I mean is that it is not pulling out the parameters

Comment: `$url = end(explode('u=', $_SERVER['argv'][0]));`